# Enabling an XML attribute on CalendarDateRangePicker using Java

Tags: java, android, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use this [CalendarDateRangePicker](https://github.com/ArchitShah248/CalendarDateRangePicker) library as a datetime range picker in an `AlertDialog`

```
private void showDateTimeRangePicker() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    DateRangeCalendarView dateRangeCalendarView = new DateRangeCalendarView(this);
    builder.setView(dateRangeCalendarView);
    builder.show();
}
```

It accepts an XML Attribute of `enable_time_selection` to enable Time selection which I need. I do not want to create an XML resource for this. The `DateRangeCalendarView` object does not seem to have a property or a function that lets me do this programmatically.

How do I enable this property / pass the XML attribute using Java from within it's Activity?

Comment: AFAICT, that attribute isn't actually used anywhere, in the current code, at least. Searching the repo gives me only two results: [one in `attrs.xml`](https://github.com/ArchitShah248/CalendarDateRangePicker/blob/master/awesome-calendar/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L13) – where the attribute is simply defined – and one in the README, in [the XML Attribute set list](https://github.com/ArchitShah248/CalendarDateRangePicker/tree/master#xml-attribute-set). Maybe it's leftover from a previous release? Or maybe something planned for a future one? Did you see that somewhere other than the README?

Comment: I've tried creating XML resource for this and the enable_time_selection attribute works in such instance. So I suppose this isn't some leftover code or a stub to be extended later.

Comment: Did you try searching the repo yourself, just to double-check? Which version are you using?

Comment: I did not do an extensive search. I used version 1.1.7.